# Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The parameterized query

Tags: c#, sql-server, powershell, ado

I am using ADO connection to Insert data into MS SQL Server 2016 from a PowerShell output from an API.

My script below:

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=XYZ; Initial Catalog=Z; Integrated Security=SSPI")
$conn.Open()  
$cmd = $conn.CreateCommand() 

$JSONResult |Select id,surname,managingDeanery
foreach($obj in $JSONResult) {  
    $Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
    $Command.Connection = $dbConnection
    $cmd.CommandText = "INSERT Client (id,surname,managingDeanery) VALUES (@id,@surname,@managingDeanery)"  
    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",$obj.id);
    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname",$obj.surname); 
    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@managingDeanery",$obj.managingDeanery);           
    $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()   
    $cmd.Parameters.clear();  
}  
$conn.Close()
```

The error I get is:

```
 Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The parameterized query '(@id int,@surname nvarchar(9),@managingDeanery nvarchar(4000))IN' 
     expects the parameter '@managingDeanery', which was not supplied."
     At line:30 char:5
     +     $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
     +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], 
           MethodInvocationException
         + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
```

I have tried using:

```
$cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@managingDeanery",'$obj.DBNull.Value');
```

But this makes all the empty fields and non empty fields as `$obj.DBNull.Value` in the `managingDeanery` column which is incorrect. Not all the data in the column is empty.

Comment: You are using quotes around the parameter value in your second working example. Did you try to use quotes around the $obj.surname ?

Comment: _$Command_ or _$cmd_ what is the correct one here?

Comment: Don't use AddWithValue. Instead, use the Add method with the proper SQL type specified (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbys3e9s.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Beside the fact, that you should not use `AddWithValue` I assume, that you must check the content of `$obj.managingDeanery`. In case of `null` you must pass `$obj.DBNull.Value` as the parameter's value

I've never used C# via *powershell*, but it should be something like

```
$cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@managingDeanery",$obj.managingDeanery ?? $obj.DBNull.Value);
```

or something like

```
$cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@managingDeanery",($obj.managingDeanery==null ? $obj.DBNull.Value : $obj.managingDeanery));
```

or a simple `if` structure...